# NumberFormatException, BigInteger in java

Tags: java

Getting following run-time error

```
C:\jdk1.6.0_07\bin>java euler/BigConCheck
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "z
"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.
java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:447)
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:314)
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:447)
        at euler.BigConCheck.conCheck(BigConCheck.java:25)
        at euler.BigConCheck.main(BigConCheck.java:71)
```

My Code

```
package euler;
import java.math.BigInteger;
class BigConCheck
{

public int[] conCheck(BigInteger big)
{
    int i=0,q=0,w=0,e=0,r=0,t=0,mul=1;
    int a[]= new int[1000];
    int b[]= new int[7];
    BigInteger rem[]= new BigInteger[4]; 
    BigInteger num[]= new BigInteger[4]; 
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)  
    num[i]=big;   // intialised num[1 to 4][0] with big
    String s="1",g="0";
    for(i=0;i<999;i++)
    s = s.concat(g);
    BigInteger divi[]= new BigInteger[4]; 

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)  
    {
        divi[i]=new BigInteger(s);  
        int z = (int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)i);

        BigInteger zz = new BigInteger("z");    // intialised div[1 to 4][0] with big
        divi[i]=divi[i].divide(zz);
    }

    for(i=0;i<996;i++)   // 5 consecative  numbers.
    {
        for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
        {
            rem[k] = num[k].mod(divi[k]);
            b[k]=rem[k].intValue();
            mul= mul*b[k]; 
            /*int z = (int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)(k+1));
        String zz = "z"; 
        BigInteger zzz = new BigInteger(zz);
        num[k]=num[k].divide(zzz);   */
        }

        a[i]=mul;
        for(int p=0;p<5;p++)
        {
            BigInteger qq = new BigInteger("10");
            num[p]=num[p].divide(qq);
        }       
    } 
    return a;
} 

public int bigestEleA(int u[])
{
    int big=0;
    for(int i=0;i<u.length;i++)
    if(big<u[i])
    big=u[i];

    return big;
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    int con5[]= new int[1000]; 
    int punCon;
    BigInteger bigest = new BigInteger("7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");


    BigConCheck bcc = new BigConCheck();
    con5=bcc.conCheck(bigest);
    punCon=bcc.bigestEleA(con5);
    System.out.println(punCon);


}
```

}

please point out whats goes wrong @ runtime and why

thanks in advance...

Comment: Someone needs to explain why they upvoted this in the first place. Or get their meds checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the line causing you grief:

```
BigInteger zz = new BigInteger("z");    // intialised div[1 to 4][0] with big
```

While `BigInteger` does work with `String`'s, those `String`'s must be parsable into numbers.

**EDIT****
Try this:

```
 Integer z = (Integer)Math.pow((double)10,(double)i);

 BigInteger zz = new BigInteger(z.toString());
```

Comment: after String gg ="z";
   BigInteger zz = new BigInteger("gg");

Comment: @user727154, you **cannot** pass non-numeric string! `"gg"` isn't a number.

Comment: @user727154, the BigInteger constructor you are using takes strings that can be converted to Base 10 numbers. `z` and `gg` cannot be converted, unless you are using err Base 64?

Comment: @user727154, "z" is a String literal, representing the actual String value of "z".  You are under the impression that "z" would convert your int primitive into a String representing the underlying number, which it won't in Java.  Perhaps you want to use the Interger object and call .toString() on it and pass that into your BigInteger constructor.

Comment: @Vineet how can i pass a int to BigInteger

Comment: @user727154, the String literal `"z"` in Java is an object. It is not a **character** (which is an int), if you are coming from C. That's why it will continue to fail on any string unless the string contains [0-9] only.

Comment: @nicoholas why can't int no. wrapped in String like String gg= "z"

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild ,nicoholas,The Elite Gentleman thanks; wrapped int in Integer, and called toString on it; its working now Error Solved

Comment: @user727154, @nicholas.hauschild, you could use a `String.valueOf()` method too.

Answer (score 3):

`new BigInteger("z");` is not meaningful. You can only pass numbers in constructor.

This is pretty obvious, so the next time you get an exception go the the exact line in your code shown in the exception stacktrace and you will most likely spot the problem.

Comment: String gg ="z"; BigInteger zz = new BigInteger(gg);
 
same error

Comment: @user727154 what number do you expect to be represented by the 'z' string? BigInteger only holds numbers.

Comment: Not a string, but as BigInteger only takes String as argument I had to do so, but it didn't worked. So I had to warped int into Integer class and call toSting() to pass parameter as string, thanks... its working now

Answer (score 3):

```
BigInteger zz = new BigInteger("z");
```

you are passing non-numerical string thats the reason.

EDIT:

It takes string but it expects the string to be a numerical value. "z" does not have any numerical meaning.

Comment: String gg ="z";
   BigInteger zz = new BigInteger(gg);

Comment: same error, BigInteger takes String as a argument and still error is same

Comment: It takes string but it expect the string to be a numerical value. "z" does not have a numerical meaning.

Answer (score 3):

`BigInteger` Javadoc states for `BigInteger(String value)`

> **Translates the decimal String
>   representation of a BigInteger into a
>   BigInteger.** The String representation
>   consists of an optional minus sign
>   followed by a sequence of one or more
>   decimal digits. The character-to-digit
>   mapping is provided by
>   Character.digit. The String may not
>   contain any extraneous characters
>   (whitespace, for example).

So your code:

```
BigInteger zz = new BigInteger("z");    // intialised div[1 to 4][0] with big
```

is totally incorrect, but this is correct:

```
BigInteger zz = new BigInteger("5566");
```

EDIT: Based on your comment, this would be simpler by using the `String.valueOf()` method:

```
int z = (int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)i);
BigInteger zz = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(z));
```

Comment: String gg ="z";
BigInteger zz = new BigInteger(gg);

Comment: @user727154, the String `"z"` is not numeric. Do you understand the meaning of the word **numeric**?

Comment: I think,with all respect z is numeric,  as int z = (int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)i); in code,   the problem was that it had to be a string so I warred it into Integer class and called toString() to convert it into String , and it worked, Thanks.

Comment: @user727154, thanks for rectifying that you wanted to use the `z` variable and create a BigInteger. I have updated my post as such.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you want this instead?

```
    int z = (int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)i);

    BigInteger zz = new BigInteger(z);
```

Note the missing quotes here. (Of course, this will only work for `i < 10`.)

Comment: thanks, yes it would have worked only if z would have been in 0-9 limit, but otherwise as it worked was, I had to warped int into Integer class and call toSting() to pass parameter as string, thanks... its working now

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is writing 
new BigInteger("",num)
instead of 
new BigInteger(""+num)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in generating longs with characters without hashing, it is possible to transform characters to long via BigInteger simply by using the constructor with a radix: `BigInteger(String value, int radix)`

There is a catch thought, the int which defines the log base, must scale not with the length of the String, but instead with the number of characters that make out the collection of characters that will be used in the creation of the String.

As far as I'm aware, for an alpha numeric collection, the int is 36 (26 + 10), this may be wrong thought.

There is also a limitation, I believe there are symbols that simply cannot be parsed, like "-" or " " or "_" (I've tried adding to the int base radix and nothing) which means the String must be transformed before parsing and it cannot be returned back to String after it being parsed via BigInteger.

Why is it useful?? I don't know haha, I have use it to autogenerate id's from Strings ,instead of using hashes, I remember somhwere this is kinda better than hashcode since a hash from String does not ensure uniqueness, an also this method as opposed to base Encoding gives extricity a long value, which may be useful for many api's that require a long id.